# Variations on Ramanujan's magic square

Tags: recreational-mathematics, magic-square

There is a well known Ramanujan's magic square of the 4th order (see Figure 1.). The underlying structure of Ramanujan's magic square is given in Figure 2.

$$\begin{array}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 22 & 12 & 18 & 87 \\ 
\hline
 88 & 17 & 9 & 25 \\
\hline 
 10 & 24 & 89 & 16 \\
\hline 
19 & 86 & 23 & 11 \\
 \hline
\end{array}$$
$$\text{Figure 1.}$$

$$\begin{array}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} & \text{D} \\ 
\hline
 \text{D}+1 & \text{C}-1 & \text{B}-3 & \text{A}+3 \\
\hline 
 \text{B}-2 & \text{A}+2 & \text{D}+2 & \text{C}-2 \\
\hline 
\text{C}+1 & \text{D}-1 & \text{A}+1 & \text{B}-1 \\
 \hline
\end{array}$$
$$\text{Figure 2.}$$

I have managed to create variation of Ramanujan's magic square , where date of the birth is given in the main diagonal rather than in the first row (see Figure 3.) .The underlying structure of this variation is given in Figure 4.

$$\begin{array}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 22 & 88 & 10 & 19 \\ 
\hline
 17 & 12 & 86 & 24 \\
\hline 
 89 & 23 & 18 & 9 \\
\hline 
11 & 16 & 25 & 87 \\
 \hline
\end{array}$$
$$\text{Figure 3.}$$

$$\begin{array}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 \text{A} & \text{D}+1 & \text{B}-2 & \text{C}+1 \\ 
\hline
 \text{C}-1 & \text{B} & \text{D}-1 & \text{A}+2 \\
\hline 
 \text{D}+2 & \text{A}+1 & \text{C} & \text{B}-3 \\
\hline 
\text{B}-1 & \text{C}-2 & \text{A}+3 & \text{D} \\
 \hline
\end{array}$$
$$\text{Figure 4.}$$

I was using trial and error method, but I am interested if there are some more concise methods for creating nontrivial variations (i.e. variations where birthdate isn't given in the first or in the fourth column, in the fourth row , etc.) of the Ramanujan's magic square?

P.S.

You can generate both types of your personal magic squares [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyVUdFqwjAUffcrijDS0FuxcTCxBLYy2JNP82WolDSJtVBSl6ZzMvbvS9JuiPNhC4Qk9xzOOfemPEzkG6vD8ZKVFX9-7ZiWDyGDAjimH4Lym2Q6TTnlm427aGk6rcK1J4BIRZQAjxMo4hmwaJYWMbEnAWE3j0nKLS4sziLHSbb4Mx3jUXnFNPuLqfAyVjpKUm87iJPUGToT7qLYGC6Wq8xADKZC7oInqaRmRuar00Hm330uRoFdvUtgs-06xU3VqJyz-mIyY-hb3-JJy0oZXpPN_i2b_Za9r5Sxmtx4gzxktFKHzuRF8x4SAuiRnRYIjpUwe0owFGdwYuFlo8z-nMDPCfP5HaAXyfQP4xYD8-FoK2vJTaPDNbqYFoKLSoa2UHTGNKqlK91JqFkha4oQHnrvJQMa-N_uXzjwULtvjsFQGuaFvwCZxcoI&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: Why do you associate such squares with Ramanujan rather than with anyone else?

Comment: @RosieF See this video: https://youtu.be/IW74oqvhSuI

Comment: The embedding of a date is cute but the result is unimpressive: there are complete compact associative 4x4 magic squares, and this one has none of [those properties](http://www.magic-squares.net/glossary.htm); as it is not complete, it is not pandiagonal either. Here's a complete compact associative magic square honouring Prof. Conway: (b. 26/12/1937, d. aged 82): \begin{array}
026&12&19&37\\82&-26&89&-51\\28&10&21&35\\-42&98&-35&73
\end{array}

Comment: Correction: it's complete and compact but not associative.

Comment: @RosieF Nice, but Conway's magic square contains negative numbers and therefore it is not so magic. Btw. thank you for the link.

Comment: Fair enough. Here's a complete compact magic square honouring Prof. Conway: (b. 26/12/1937):
\begin{array}
026&12&19&37\\
22&34&29&9\\
28&10&21&35\\
18&38&25&13\end{array}

Comment: @RosieF Did you make this one?

Comment: Yes indeed I did. It's fairly easy.

Comment: @RosieF Do you have program or algorithm?

Comment: Yes. SE doesn't like long conversations in comments. Because of this, and because you are interested, I will prepare a separate question.

Comment: @RosieF Thanks.

Comment: See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659546/how-can-a-compact-complete-4-times4-magic-square-be-constructed-with-4-given/3659553#3659553)